# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/resteasy/annotations/SseElementType

Tags: spring-security, spring-data-jpa, quarkus

The project is generated in line command then builder. I have an exception raised by this class `ResteasyCommonProcessor.java`. I wish to know if it is due to the absence of dependencies or other:

```
The POM for org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-core:jar:4.4.1.Final is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-json-binding-provider:jar:4.4.1.Final is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-json-p-provider:jar:4.4.1.Final is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson2-provider:jar:4.4.1.Final is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-spring-web:jar:4.4.1.Final is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
```

I create quarkus project with spring dependencies but when I build the project I get this error

```
ERROR [io.qua.dev.DevModeMain] Failed to start Quarkus: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/resteasy/annotations/SseElementType
                at io.quarkus.resteasy.common.deployment.ResteasyCommonProcessor.<clinit>(ResteasyCommonProcessor.java:59)
                at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
                at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
                at io.quarkus.deployment.util.ServiceUtil.classesNamedIn(ServiceUtil.java:31)
                at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader.loadStepsFrom(ExtensionLoader.java:206)
                at io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor.run(QuarkusAugmentor.java:85)
                at io.quarkus.runner.RuntimeRunner.run(RuntimeRunner.java:114)
                at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.doStart(DevModeMain.java:178)
                at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:96)
                at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:67)
        Caused by: **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.SseElementType**
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
                at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
```

Project `pom.xml` with the dependencies

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ml.kalansow</groupId>
    <artifactId>kalansow-ciwara</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <quarkus-plugin.version>1.1.1.Final</quarkus-plugin.version>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-universe-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>1.1.1.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
        <surefire-plugin.version>2.22.1</surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-spring-di</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-spring-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-elytron-security-properties-file</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <systemProperties>
                                        <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                                    </systemProperties>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <name>kalansow</name>
    <url>kalansow.ml</url>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not add the `resteasy-core` dependency as `quarkus-resteasy` will bring it to you.

By doing this you can have a mismatch between the version of resteasy supported by Quarkus and the one you specify manually.

Please remove the `resteasy-core` dependency from your `pom.xml`.

Comment: If it works, please accept the answer for other that may have the isuse knows that it fixed it.